# I need a menu in p5.js

Tags: p5.js

I need help writing a menu for my p5.js game I am working on. I haven't used p5.js before, and the jam I am working on ends in 2 days. If possible, I would like it as a rectangle rather than a stock button so it looks better.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I have quit the jam, because I don't know anything much about p5.js.
I will still work on it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could use buttons for the menu and to have that flat color button you could use CSS.

**sketch.js**

```
function setup(){
    button1 = createButton("something");
    button1.class('button');
}
```

**style.css**

```
.button {
    background-color: rgb(0, 168, 219);
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Every time I try to run it nothing appears. I am new to p5.js, so I have no idea why nothing is showing up.

Comment: sorry i forget to add ' ' to button. change the line to    button1.class('button');